# Subsetting a Spatial Data Frame using Input from InputSelect

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am trying to subset a spatial data frame using an input from InputSelect in a shiny app.

1. outside of the app this is working :

   ```
   SDF2 <- SDF1%>% subset(VAR >200)
   ```
2. inside the shiny app this is NOT working =>

-in the UI :

```
  selectInput("choice", "", choices = "VAR" )
```

-in the Server :

```
   InputVar<-input$choice
   SDF2 <- SDF1 %>% subset(InputVar >200)
```

Why 1  works and 2 doesn't ?

Any hint would be really appreciated !

Comment: Try this: `SDF2 <- reactive({ SDF1 %>% subset(input$choice > 200) })`. And most likely `VAR` should not be quoted here: `choices = "VAR"`. But if you really want help you should provide a [fully reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @nrussell But `input$choice` will still be a string. You cannot use `subset()` with a column name specified by string. This question probably address the real issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075529/r-subset-based-on-variable-column-name

Comment: @MrFlick That's a very good point.

Comment: @MrFlick, this was exactly where my problem lay. Thak you a lot !

Comment: Thank you @nrussell as well for your reply!